# Loose quality when render UIImageView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am using below code in swift to capture a UIImageView into one image. It works but the image is not as same quality as the one showing on the UIImageView. Is there a way to configure the quality when capture this image?

```
private func getScreenshow(imageView:UIImageView) -> UIImage{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageView.frame.size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    imageView.layer.renderInContext(context!)
    let screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenShot, nil, nil, nil)
    return screenShot
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After some searching I figured out the issue. I use below code to replace the "UIGraphicsBeginImageContext" and it works.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.imageView.frame.size, true, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

This code looks pretty weird (why don’t you just use `imageView.image`?) but I don’t know the full context of your use case.

As you found, the reason for the loss of quality is you are ignoring the screen’s retina scale.

Read the documentation for [UIGraphicsBeginImageContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginImageContext) and [UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions) and you’ll see the former uses a ‘scale factor of `1.0`’.

Comment: Because there are many other sub-views shown on the imageView.

Comment: By issue was not related to this question, as I was converting a UIBezierPath to UIImage. However your comment about the scale factor was one I had ignored. For some reason, I had put scale as 1. I made it 0 and everything looked beautiful! Thanks! :)